Are journals interested in reviews of books that are several years old?
It seems that most book reviews are published within a year of the publication of the book. I assume that the more recent the book, the more interested a journal will be in publishing a review. But at what point do journal editors begin losing interest in book reviews? When the book is 6 months old? 12 months old? 3 years old?
I recently came across an unreviewed book that is a couple years old; I am wondering if any journal would be interested in my review of it.

It would probably take special circumstances for it to be "interesting" to a publisher, such as fresh interest in the book, or, at least, the topic of the book. This might be the case in a fast moving field.
If you can find a way to ask an editor if they have any interest, you can try that. But you can also submit a review and take your chances. It might happen, or not, depending on many factors up to and including the need to fill a few pages in an issue.

Thank you. So what is the general "cut off" point? 1 year?

@Doubt many/most journals that publish reviews include these details on their information pages or simply say to contact the editor about reviews. Timelines depend upon fields and journals.
